# JavaScript for each record in my view

Tags: javascript, html

I have a VIEW where I display a table with 15 records (15 rows) and 5 columns, but the very thing that matters is a column, "Actions". In it I have 1 button, "Preview", that when clicking, I want to open a window with a message, for tests.

However, only the first record, when clicking the "View" button, displays the message window, the other 14 records do not.

How do I make all records / lines display the message?

Follow the code below:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="header text-center" style="width: 100px;"> Ações </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tabela">     
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @this.Hidden("IdClient").Value(item.Id)
                    <a id="visualizarCliente" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-visualizar" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Visualizar" target="_blank" 
                      href="@Url.Action(MVC.Painel.Clientes.Visualizar(item.Id))">
                        <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#visualizarCliente").click(function () {
            var idCliente = $("#IdClient").val();
            window.alert("Teste");
        })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the id selector and it can not be repeated. Switch to any other selector, such as data-toggle = "tooltip" for example.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("a[data-toggle='tooltip']").click(function () {
            window.alert("Teste");
        })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `ID` which always be used for something **UNIQUE**. Try to use `CLASS` instead. Your function should goes something like this one example:

```
$(function () {
        $(".btn-visualizar").click(function () {
            var idCliente = $(this).parent().find("#IdClient").val();
            window.alert("Teste");
        })
    });
```

In the given example the line `$(this).parent().find("#IdClient").val();` specifies that this would be it's nearest *element value* as it should be.